# Javascript Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, regex

```
alert(/[a-zA-Z0-9 -_\.,]+/.test('test_string@');
```

I currently have the above code and I want to it to return `false` whenever something in the string doesn't match. For example, the string above has an `@`. The return would be `true` because `test_string` matches.

Is there a javascript function or some code that could help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are beginning `^` and end `$` of string matches:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9 \-_\.,]+$/.test('test_string@')
// ----------^ Also notice that escape! ;)
```

Comment: doesn't that return true because `@` matches?

Comment: @Thorpe why does the `@` match? It's not in the character set.

Comment: Box9. I feel like a noob. I just forgot my regex today.

Comment: @Thorpe, no worries, regex is one of those things you really need to be awake for ;)